# PyOpenCL Matrix multiplication

Tags: python, opencl, ati, pyopencl

I have this code for matrix multiplication using pyopenCL.
My problem is that the result is wrong in some matrices, and I dont understand why.
After some research i think its related with global size of something like that but i dont understand how to set that values.

For example:

matrices using numpy dtype = float32

matrix 1:

```
[[ 0.99114645  0.09327769  0.90075564  0.8913309 ]
[ 0.59739089  0.13906649  0.94246316  0.65673178]
[ 0.24535166  0.68942326  0.41361505  0.5789603 ]
[ 0.31962237  0.17714553  0.49025267  0.21861202]]
```

matrix2:

```
[[ 0.41509482  0.82779616  0.74143827  0.37681136]
[ 0.88058949  0.01039944  0.4342753   0.45752665]
[ 0.60375261  0.21243185  0.88312167  0.97394323]
[ 0.60855824  0.69482827  0.61627114  0.57155776]]
```

expected result:

```
[[ 1.57981943  1.63210835  2.12016045  1.80288424]
[ 1.3391085   1.15248911  1.7403561   1.58199609]
[ 1.31099532  0.70041376  1.20338154  1.14162762]
[ 0.71769556  0.52246746  0.88158722  0.8039138 ]]
```

script result:

```
[[ 1.20828819  0.73175305  1.64546931  1.42526579]
[ 1.13179159  0.46403384  1.20692348  1.14317513]
[ 1.25328159  0.86723316  1.58679342  1.40186214]
[ 1.35214019  0.6795128   1.73811913  1.48048854]]
```

script:

```
def openCL_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2, res):

import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

mf = cl.mem_flags
a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=matrix1)
b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=matrix2)
dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, matrix1.nbytes )


prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void multiplymatrices(const unsigned int size, __global float * matrix1, __global float * matrix2, __global float * res) {

    int i = get_global_id(1); 
    int j = get_global_id(0);

    res[i + size * j] = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        res[i + size * j] += matrix1[i + size * k] * matrix2[k + size * j];
    }

    }
    """).build()

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()

prg.multiplymatrices(queue, matrix1.shape, None,np.int32(len(matrix1)) ,a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)

final_matrix = np.empty_like(matrix1)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, final_matrix , dest_buf)

print  final_matrix


delta_t = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
print 'OpenCL Multiplication: ' + str(delta_t)

return final_matrix
```

Thank you!

Comment: removing cuda tag as this doesn't appear to have anything to do with cuda

Comment: @RobertCrovella you beat me to it :D

Comment: Where are you initializing the output buffer to 0?

Comment: yes, i did that and the result is the same

Comment: You say the result is wrong with some matrices. For which matrices is it correct? Did you try to set one of the matrices to the Identity?
Can you update the code with the output matrix initialization? The current code seems to be  incrementing an uninitialized buffer.

Comment: for example matrices like [1 2 3][4 5 6 ][7 8 9] * identity matrix the result is correct. I also edited the code with initialization of the buffer.

Comment: Both paths of your code may have different conventions on matrix storage. Try exchanging matrices A and B in the OpenCL call to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the kernel does all right.
I can even call script result correct. It all depends on how you treat your matrices :-)
If you want your expected result. I'd change this:

```
res[i + size * j] += matrix1[i + size * k] * matrix2[k + size * j];
```

to this:

```
res[i + size * j] += matrix1[k + size * i] * matrix2[j + size * k];
```

Hope this helps.